# Why do I get this weird image in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do something similar to a chess game. I have a `createBoard.py` file and `Knight.py` file.
I defined the `img` as a global variable like this and created a `click` function for each square in the board, this is in `createBoard.py`:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("knightImage.gif"))
def click(cell):
    position = getPosition(cell, cells)
    removePreviousPosition(cells)
    goToPosition(cells, position, img)
```

Then when I want to go into a position, I remove the image of every square in the board (`removePreviousPosition`) and go to a given position (`goToPosition`). The game is played only with a single knight, so this is not a problem. This is in `Knight.py`:

```
def removePreviousPosition(cells):
    for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            (cells[row][col])["image"]=""

def goToPosition(cells, position, img):
    row = position[0]
    col = position[1]
    (cells[row][col])["image"]=img
```

However, even though removal works fine, when I go into a position, I get this instead of a knight image:

[image: Weird Image]

I have an init file.

---

Edit 1: These are the creation of the board and knightImage.gif:

```
cells = []
for row in range(8):
cells.append([])
for col in range(8):
    cell = Button(window)
    cell.config(height=3, width=6)
    if (row+col)%2==0:
        cell.config(bg="#f0d9b5")
    else: cell.config(bg="#b58863")
    cell.grid(row=row, column=col)
    cell.configure(command=lambda putCell=cell: click(putCell))
    cells[row].append(cell)
```

[knightImage.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTwtF.gif)

Comment: How do you create the board?  The cause may be at the line `(cells[row][col])["image"]=""`.  You should assign it a dummy image instead of empty string.

Comment: Please share the complete, but minimum code necessary to run your example, i.e. the `imports`, the code that actually draws the knight on the screen and `knightImage.gif`. Thank you.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried assigning another image before the knight image but I still get the same result. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added in the creation of the board and knightImage.gif. I also tried (cells[row][col]).config(image="").

Comment: Okay guys, I was able to come up with a workaround. Thank you.